# How can I init a list according to the game state if the game is running or not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this monobehaviour script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompareObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainGame;
    public string comparisonObjects;
    public float waitTime;
    public List<GameObject> allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
    public bool startComparingAtStart = false;

    private Coroutine comparer;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying == false)
        {
            allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
        }
        else
        {
            allobjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();
        }

        if (startComparingAtStart == true)
        {
            StartComparing();
        }
    }

    public void StartComparing()
    {
        mainGame.SetActive(false);

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = StartCoroutine(Compare());
        }
    }

    public void StopComparing()
    {
        if (comparer != null)
        {
            comparisonObjects = "";
            allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
            StopCoroutine(comparer);
            mainGame.SetActive(true);

            comparer = null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Compare()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (GameObject go in allobjects)
            {
                if (go.name != "Game Manager")
                {
                    comparisonObjects = go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object";
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And editor script for buttons in inspector :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(CompareObjects))]
public class CompareObjectsButton : Editor
{
    private CompareObjects compareObjects;

    private void OnEnable()
    {

        compareObjects = (CompareObjects)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        CompareObjects myTarget = (CompareObjects)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Compare Objects"))
        {
            myTarget.StartComparing();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Stop"))
        {
            myTarget.StopComparing();
        }
    }
}
```

This part is not working :

```
if (Application.isPlaying == false)
{
    allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
}
else
{
    allobjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();
}
```

When running the game and clicking the start Compare Objects button if I will click the Stop button it will reset the List allObjects to length 0.

But if instead clicking the Stop button I just strop the game the allObjects list will be empty but the length will keep be over 5000 items. It's the items will be empty but I want that when the game is not running the list to be length 0.

Not sure why it keep the list length over 5000 items and how to reset it to length 0.

Tried to use the :

```
Application.isPlaying
```

But it's not working.

This is what I tried so far :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class CompareObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainGame;
    public string comparisonObjects;
    public float waitTime;
    public List<GameObject> allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
    public bool startComparingAtStart = false;

    private Coroutine comparer;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying == false)
        {
            allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
        }
        else
        {
            allobjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();
        }

        if (startComparingAtStart == true)
        {
            StartComparing();
        }
    }

    public void StartComparing()
    {
        mainGame.SetActive(false);

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = StartCoroutine(Compare());
        }
    }

    public void StopComparing()
    {
        if (comparer != null)
        {
            comparisonObjects = "";
            allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
            StopCoroutine(comparer);
            mainGame.SetActive(true);

            comparer = null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Compare()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (GameObject go in allobjects)
            {
                if (go.name != "Game Manager")
                {
                    comparisonObjects = go.name + " >>>>> " + go.scene.name + " >>>>> is active object";
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if the comparing is working the Coroutine is in the middle and I quit the game pressing the play button to quit the game the whole editor is freezing and I need to force close it in the Task Manager.

Comment: Why do you think you have to reset it at all? When the Playmode is left anything (except Assets) will be reset to the default values they had before the Playmode anyway...

Comment: @derHugo It seems to be working now fine without the [ExecuteAlways] and without the Application.isPlaying. It's just before sometimes when quit the game while the loop was in the middle the whole editor was freezing.  Now it seems to be working fine.  Not sure what happened.

Comment: Did you also have a look at [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html)? I would reset the list there and not use an editor script for that.

Comment: The editor script is for the buttons in the inspector. You suggest to use the  OnValidate in the mono script for that ?

Comment: yes I mean instead of `ExecuteAlways` and doing it in `Start` I guess you could simply do it in `OnValidate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code `if (Application.isPlaying == false)` not working in your case because it places in MonoBehaviour's Start method which called only in playmode by default.

To make code workable you can move `allobjects` initialization to `StartComparing`/`StopComparing` methods or play with [ExecuteInEditMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) or [ExecuteAlways](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteAlways.html) attributes to run code in editor mode.